# Understanding an instance of upper bound, lower bound algorithmic analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

I am continuing on my task of understanding asymptotic analysis. It may be best to just have a meta post, if mods would prefer. Anyway:

I have two functions:

```
 f(n) = n^2
 g(n) = (log n)^80
```

From analysis with l'Hopitals rule:

```
 lim(n->∞) f(n)/g(n) = f'(n)/g'(n)
```

Which leaves us with us with:

```
 f'(n)/g'(n) = 2n/(80*(log n / √2)
```

Which will eventually lead us to:

```
 0/g''(n) = 0
```

Which, as I understand it, shows that **f(n) = o(g(n))**

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No. L'Hopital must not be applied if either the numerator or denominator do not evaluate to zero. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461120/when-to-stop-using-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog how would I show this? Simple inspection will point out how much faster g(n) grows...

Comment: I gave a link in your last post - [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial). It shows that you have been mislead by the raised power.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog so the opposite of what I'm positing is true, you'd just have to have mind-blowingly large input sizes? The proof there, unless I'm misinterpreting it, is using l'Hopital to arrive at it's conclusion...

Comment: Again, L'Hopital is incorrect if either limit is non-zero. Not my words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply L'Hopital rule either if both of numerator and denominator converge to zero or infinity. So Your approach is true in general. But you made mistake to compute g'(n).

```
g'(n) = (80 * log(n)) * 1/(2 ln (n))
  => f'(n)/g'(n) = 2n / ((80 * log(n)^79) * 1/(n ln(2))) 
   = 2n^2 / 80log(n)^79 ln(2)
```

At the moment, the limit of f'(n)/g'(n) is ∞/∞ too. So you can apply L'Hopital rule again. But the result is same. But after 80th apply, you have this:

```
2^80 n^2 / 80! ln(2)^80
  =>  lim(n->∞) f(n)/g(n) = ∞
```

Thus, **g(n) = o(f(n))**.